# How to select a value from a Dropdown in Protractor

Tags: drop-down-menu, protractor

I want to select a value from a dropbox. The contents from dropbox do not have values or ID, instead, they have a title. This is the HTML for one of the contents and for the dropdown. The id below is from dropbox. With this information, I am just able to select the dropbox, not the values.

`````
<span class="select2-selection__placeholder">Select reason</span>
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-e5dt-container" role="textbox" title="01 - <Change of mind, back to stock>">01 - Change of mind, back to stock</span>
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-e5dt-container" role="textbox" title="04 - <Production Fault, to recovery>">04 - Production Fault, to recovery</span>````
`````

Comment: could you provide us with the entire dropdown? or at least the dropdown element with a few options

Comment: @JoaquinCasco please see my update above

Comment: @IngriddBrito: Thanks for the info, enough to write a code on it.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem statement all you need to do is:

1. Find the dropdown using element
2. Click the dropdown
3. Click the option

```
it("should select the dropdown." async () => {
    await $("span.select2-selection__placeholder").click();
    //add sleep to give a time for the options to reveal or use an explicit wait 
    //here. I prefer the latter.
    await browser.sleep(1000)
    // click the option '01 - Change of mind, back to stock'
    await $$("span#select2-e5dt-container"").get(0).click();
});
```

Lemme know how it works out for you!

Comment: Hi @Puja, I got this error message: _Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, span#select2-e5dt-container)_ This is the code: `it('should select reason code', async function() { <\br>
    await $('span.select2-selection__placeholder').click(); //click on the dropdown
    //add sleep to give a time for the options to reveal or use an explicit wait     
    await browser.sleep(1000);    
    await $$('span#select2-e5dt-container').get(0).click();
    });
})
`

Answer (score 0):

1. Identify Drop Down and click on it
2. Wait for DropDown options to be displayed (use ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf())

   ```
   var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
   var filteroption = "Production Fault, to recovery";
   this.DDOptions = element.all(by.css('[role="textbox"]'));
   ```

   //Click on the Drop Down

   // Wait for Drop Down options to be visible

`browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(this.DDOptions.get(0), 500, "DD option not visible timing out"));`

```
this.DDOptions.filter(function (elem, index) {
    return elem.getText().then(function (text) {
      return text.toUpperCase() === filteroption.toUpperCase();
    });
  }).then(function (filteredElements) {
      filteredElements[0].click();
  });
```